# How to retain field values on error in a dynamic gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a page which has a GridView on it, which is populated from a database. Some of the columns in the GridView have text boxes, as well as Checkboxes.

When the user saves the page, the page may error if they have not entered their data correctly. At this point, I need to re-display what they have entered already so they can simply make the correction instead of having to change everything from scratch again.

The part that I'm having trouble with is the fact that this GridView can have a variable number of rows, so in turn a variable number of fields. What would be a good way to retain those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.Cancel = true;` will do the trick

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    //Display Message here       
}
```